# What the different between -b:v <target bitrate> and -b <target bitrate> FFmpeg flags?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264

I need to bound the video bitrate, which flag is better to use? I re-encode h.264 video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:v` after the `b` is an example of a stream specifier, which directs and limits the streams to which the option is applied. So, `-option:a:2` would only apply to the third audio output stream, whereas `-option:a` would apply to all audio output streams. `-option` would apply to all streams.

However, in the case of `-b`, ffmpeg will catch this syntax and treat it the same as `-b:v`.

Also, see https://superuser.com/a/1219824 for guide to how the order of options affects result.