# Understanding ffmpeg map option

Tags: ffmpeg

I came across the following command in a [blog post](https://blog.zazu.berlin/internet-programmierung/mpeg-dash-and-hls-adaptive-bitrate-streaming-with-ffmpeg.html) which creates different quality video streams that are packaged into DASH format via the [dash muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#dash-2).

```
ffmpeg -i $VIDEO_IN \
    -preset $PRESET_P -keyint_min $GOP_SIZE -g $GOP_SIZE -sc_threshold 0 \
    -r $FPS -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 1 -ar 44100 \
    -map v:0 -s:0 $V_SIZE_1 -b:v:0 2M -maxrate:0 2.14M -bufsize:0 3.5M \
    -map v:0 -s:1 $V_SIZE_2 -b:v:1 145k -maxrate:1 155k -bufsize:1 220k \
    -map v:0 -s:2 $V_SIZE_3 -b:v:2 365k -maxrate:2 390k -bufsize:2 640k \
    -map v:0 -s:3 $V_SIZE_4 -b:v:3 730k -maxrate:3 781k -bufsize:3 1278k \
    -map v:0 -s:4 $V_SIZE_4 -b:v:4 1.1M -maxrate:4 1.17M -bufsize:4 2M \
    -map v:0 -s:5 $V_SIZE_5 -b:v:5 3M -maxrate:5 3.21M -bufsize:5 5.5M \
    -map v:0 -s:6 $V_SIZE_5 -b:v:6 4.5M -maxrate:6 4.8M -bufsize:6 8M \
    -map v:0 -s:7 $V_SIZE_6 -b:v:7 6M -maxrate:7 6.42M -bufsize:7 11M \
    -map v:0 -s:8 $V_SIZE_6 -b:v:8 7.8M -maxrate:8 8.3M -bufsize:8 14M \
    -map 0:a \
    -init_seg_name init\$RepresentationID\$.\$ext\$ -media_seg_name chunk\$RepresentationID\$-\$Number%05d\$.\$ext\$ \
    -use_template 1 -use_timeline 1  \
    -seg_duration 4 -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" \
    -f dash Dash/dash.mpd
```

The thing I'm struggling to understand is how the maps work. I've read the [Map docs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map) but they don't seem to have a comparable example.

1. Why is -map v:0 used for every video stream?
2. Why does the first map line operate on stream 0 (e.g. -b:v:0) and the next map line operates on stream 1 (e.g. -b:v:1), etc.

Would really appreciate a breakdown.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is -map v:0 used for every video stream?

The correct string should be `-map 0:v:0`. The file index was omitted and thus implicitly interpreted as file index 0. Such syntax is best avoided.

> Why does the first map line operate on stream 0 (e.g. -b:v:0)

Don't think in terms of lines or proximity of options in relation to a map. The 0 in `-b:v:0` is part of a stream specifier and targets which *output* stream to target.

See

[What the different between -b:v <target bitrate> and -b <target bitrate> FFmpeg flags?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60043169/)

https://superuser.com/q/1219784/

Comment: Interesting, so could all the maps be together and produce same result?

e.g. ... -map 0:v:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:v:0 -map0:v:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:v:0 -s:0 $V_SIZE_1 -b:v:0 2M -maxrate:0 2.14M -bufsize:0 3.5M -s:1 $V_SIZE_2 -b:v:1 145k -maxrate:1 155k -bufsize:1 220k